# What is the URL to access the jBoss Business Central Maven Repository when running on localhost

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I have downloaded the jbpm-server-7.30.0.Final-dist zip file from the JBoss website, extracted the contents, and then run the standalone.bat file. The Wildfly server starts and I can see the deployments for the Business Central and Kie Server web applications. The Business Central website works correctly at this url http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central. I can create a simple project, build and deploy it, all local with no extra repositories.

Within Business Central I can navigate to the Artifacts page and download the JAR for my simple project. I can install the downloaded jar into the local maven and work with it in my Java application.

The question is - Can I access the repository as a normal maven repo in a java projects via the POM.XML file? If this can be done what is the url to access it?

I tries various urls ..

http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central/maven/project_name

http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central/.m2maven/project_name

http://127.0.0.1:8080/kie-wb/maven/project_name

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.2/html/development_guide/uploading_artifacts_to_maven_repository) suggests

```
[protocol]://[hostname]:[port]/[context-root]/maven2/[groupId replacing '.' with '/']/[artifactId]/[version]/[artifactId]-[version].jar
```

And provides an example:

```
http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
```

Perhaps it's the 'project_name' bit that you need to change?